# Select range until cell with certain text in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to select header / first row and data under it from columns C to O 
Until the first cell in column C has the word "Estimated"
I came up with this VBA code based on another answer on stackoverflow, but it doesn't seem to be working

All help is deeply appreciated!!

```
Range("C1").Select
For i = 1 To 9999
If ISNUMBER(SEARCH(ActiveCell.Offset(0, i), "Estimated")) = TRUE Then Exit For
If ISNUMBER(SEARCH(ActiveCell.Offset(0, i), "Estimated")) = FALSE Then Exit For
Next
If ISNUMBER(SEARCH(ActiveCell.Offset(0, i), "Estimated")) = TRUE Then             
    Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 15), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + i - 1)).Select
```

`

Comment: why not use the `Range.Find` method? Also, you [probably don't need to `Select` anything or use the `Activate/ActiveCell`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) (and it should generally be avoided).

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
range(cells(1, "C"), cells(application.match("Estimated", columns(3), 0)-1, "O")).select
```

Not sure from your narrative whether the row containing "Estimated" was to be included or not. The `-1` tells it not to include the "Estimated" row.

Comment: Thanks for the response. it is supposed to exclude it. When I ran it, I got "type mismatch" as an error.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
Range("O1", Columns(3).Find("Estimated", , xlValues, xlPart)).Select ' to include row with "Estimated" in column C
```

or

```
Range("O1", Columns(3).Find("Estimated", , xlValues, xlPart).offset(-1)).Select ' to exclude row with "Estimated" in column C
```

Comment: Thanks for having both of them. I used the second one, but when I ran it, I got "object variable or with block variable not set" as an error.

Comment: Is “Estimated” possibly not there?